# resolve Ambiguous use of appendingPathComponent error

Tags: swift3, xcode8

The code below worked great in an app I published and updated multiple times using swift 2.2. I just migrated over to swift 3 and now I get the following compile time error; "Ambiguous use of appendingPathComponent" with the line:

```
 let PDFPathFileName = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName as String)
```

In this:

```
 func returnPDFPath() -> String {
      let path:NSArray =         NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
      let documentDirectory: AnyObject = path.object(at: 0) as AnyObject
      let PDFPathFileName = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

      return PDFPathFileName
 }

 @IBAction func reveiwPDFSendCliked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let pdfPathWithFileName = returnPDFPath()

    generatePDFs(pdfPathWithFileName)
 }
```

This code is responsible for returning the file path to the documentDirectory that will be used to save a PDF file when a user clicks a review and save PDF button. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`appendingPathComponent` method is a method of `NSString`, not `AnyObject`.

Change this line:

```
let documentDirectory: AnyObject = path.object(at: 0) as AnyObject
```

to:

```
let documentDirectory = path.object(at: 0) as! NSString
```

But you should try to use the appropriate types as much as possible.

Try this:

```
func returnPDFPath() -> String {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = path.first! as NSString
    let PDFPathFileName = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

    return PDFPathFileName
}
```

This code assumes that `path` has at least one value (which is should).

Comment: No method is a method of `AnyObject`. To find what class has a given method, search for it in the reference documentation in Xcode.